# How can I customize SQL keywords in SQL Workbench/J

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am looking to customize SQL Workbench/J a bit more for Amazon Redshift.

Specifically, I am using the FLOAT8 data type and the "Format SQL" command doesn't recognize that as a type so it doesn't capitalize it or align it with the other types in my CREATE TABLE statements

I've looked here: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/settings.html
but i'm not seeing a setting for adding additional keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this in workbench.settings file. I have tried adding date/ time literals there, not so sure about FLOAT8.
Reference: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/settings.html

Comment: as my question says - i already looked there - i have that exact link in my question...